# SQL search with like

Tags: sql

I,m trying to make a query for this table which it have the following columns.

`from` , `to`, `Range` with values like

```
1,  100, A: 
101,200, B: 
201,300, C:
```

The columns are integer.

a user is going to give a number and I have to get on which rate is. Let say, the user send `105`, I know that with a query I can get that it is on range `B`. But the problem is that sometimes users do not know the complete number that is going to be sent. Let say they only know the first two digits of the number, something like 10. I have to return all the possibilities that could involve `l0`. Let say, 10-101-1001-10001. The problem is that If I use `LIKE` I will not receive all the values because I do not have them in a column.

Any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: Could users elect to *send* only last digits or digits from the middle of a number?

Comment: You're going to need to narrow things down a bit. You can't possibly expect to return all possibilities that involve 10 since that would be infinite. Also if you don't store the values you're looking for in a column, how do you associate them with a range? Or are all ranges simply blocks of 100? If that's the case, skip the SQL query and just come up with an algorithm to compute the range.

Comment: Is it only starting with the characters you're sending?  In any case, if you converted the columns to varchar, you could use `LIKE`.   In your example, `LIKE '10%'` would match '10','101',etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your case (**give first two digits**), you can use `substr` to pick the first two digits of FROM and corresponding head of TO (length(to||'')-length(from||'')+2). Then compare them with user input to find the range.

With this query, you can get all ranges which contain number like what user send.

Use user input of **12** as an example, result will be ranges contain number like '12%':

```
select from, to, range from
(select Integer(substr(from,1,2)) substr_from, 
        Integer(substr(to,1,length(to||'')-length(from||'')+2) substr_to, 
        from, to, range 
from your_table)
where (substr_from<=12 and substr_to>=12)
or (from<=12 and to>=12)
```

Below table will show the values of `from, to, substr_from, substr_to`

```
1     100    1    100
101   200    10   20
201   300    20   30
...................
901   1000   90   100
1001  1100   10   11
1101  1200   11   12
...................
9901  10000  99   100
10001 10100  10   10
10101 10200  10   10
...................
```

Since input is 12, these ranges will be returned: 1-100,101-200,1101-1200,1201-1300...

Of course this won't work if given digits is in the middle.